# VBA RegEx for Properties, Functions and Subs

Tags: regex, vba

I need to scan Application.VBE.ActiveProject.VBComponent.CodeModule for all lines that define Properties, Functions and Subs. I want to retrieve the scope, the type, the name and the return variable type, if it is available.

Matching lines are for example

- `Private Property Get Attribute() As String`
- `Public Sub calculateTotal()`
- `Friend Function getIdentifier() As Long`

I iteratively developed a regular expression which is supposed to match

- the keyword `Public`, `Friend` or `Private`
- followed by a blank
- followed by the keyword `Property`, `Sub` or `Function`
- followed by a blank
- followed by the optional keyword `Get` or `Set` (if it is a property)
- followed by the name (consisting of arbitrary literals and underscores)
- followed by brackets, which can contain parameters
- followed by the optional keyword `As`
- followed by the optional variable type

and ended up with

- `(Public|Friend|Private)` (captured)
- `(?: )`
- `(Property|Sub|Function)` (captured)
- `(?: )`
- `(?:[Get |Set ]*)` (here it starts to become ugly, I guess)
- `(\w+)` (captured)
- `(?:\([\w\s]+\))`
- `(?:[As ]*)`
- `(\w*)` (captured)

or in a "word" `(Public|Friend|Private)(?: )(Property|Sub|Function)(?: )(?:[Get |Set ]*)(\w+)(?:\([\w\s]+\))(\w*)`. I tried to build and debug the regular expression with [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) but were not able to get it working. I am obviously lacking the knowledge to safely include the desired parts and to exclude the optional parts of the expression.

Comment: Regex will only get you so far. Parsing VBA is harder than it seems. Have you considered using the Rubberduck VBA add-in for the VBE?

Comment: For example, your current approach is omitting Property Lets, and Declare statements, and Types and Enums.

Comment: And you're assuiming that there won't be any evil line_continuations between, for example, *Public* and *Sub*

Comment: I will have a look at Rubberduck - maybe it will help in other situations. The above mentioned matching lines are only examples as you might have already guessed and Property Let is covered by the regex. I do not need to scan Declare statements, Enums, Consts, Types etc - I need the data to auto-generate UML class diagrams. The underscore line continuations are really an issue - but I will code around it. Thanks!

Comment: The latest RubberDuck source includes a type library for working with a project's structure. If you can fork and build from source, you'll have what u need.

Comment: I will have a look into it - thanks again.

Comment: Also note, you're not capturing `Property Let` members =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(Public|Friend|Private)\s+(Property|Sub|Function)(\s+[GS]et)?\s+(\w+)\s*(\([^()]*\))(\s+As\s+\w+)?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL0sE4/2)

Explanation:

```
(Public|Friend|Private)  # keyword
\s+                      # blank
(Property|Sub|Function)  # keyword2
(\s+[GS]et)?             # Optional blank + Get/Set
\s+(\w+)                 # blank + name
\s*(\([^()]*\))          # Optional blank+compulsory parentheses
(\s+As\s+\w+)?           # Optional As +variable type
```

The main point is that to make a *sequence* optional, you need to apply *grouping* with a `?` quantifier after it. Say, to optionally match blank + `As` you need `\s+` (1 or more whitespaces) and `As` wrapped in a `(` and `)?`: `(\s+As)?`. Your `[Get |Set ]*` matches zero or more `G`, `e`, `t`, space, `|` or `S` characters as `[...]` is a *character class* that matches a single character from the set/range(s).

Note that `\([^()]*\)` matches a string like `(no-round-brackets-inside)` because `[^()]` is a negated character class matching any character but `(` and `)`.

Comment: OMG - I wish I were that skillful and fast - thank you!!! And I learned a lot from your solution ... ;)

Comment: Did already - but on this StackExchange site my reputation enforces that it takes 15 minutes until it is shown. ;)

Comment: No, 15 minutes are required to pass before an answer can be *accepted*.

Comment: This will fail to match `[square-bracketed identifiers]` ...which are legal

Comment: @Mat'sMug: These are not part of the question. If OP needs more help, let OP come back and precise the question.

Comment: Just wondered: If I want to exclude the " As " from the last group, is there a more sophisticated expression than `((?:\sAs\s)([\w\d]+))?`? This will result in $5 - and I would love to have $4 ...

Comment: Do you mean [`(Public|Friend|Private)\s+(Property|Sub|Function)(\s+[GS]et)?\s+(\w+)\s*(\([^()]*\))(?:\s+As\s+(\w+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/zL0sE4/4)? Note that `[\w\d]` makes no sense as `\w` already includes (and matches) `\d`.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I meant - now I can go to bed and sleep tight - thx again!

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, regex is "fun". There's an easier and more powerful way to do this.

It's still at prototype stage, but [Rubberduck 2.0](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases) will (it's still alpha.. and buggy) expose a COM API that lets you write code like this:

```
Public Sub ListMembers()

    Dim parser As New Rubberduck.ParserState
    parser.Initialize Application.VBE
    parser.Parse

    Dim i As Variant
    Dim item As Declaration
    For Each i In parser.UserDeclarations
        Set item = i

        If IsMember(item.DeclarationType) Then
            Debug.Print item.ParentDeclaration.Name & "." & item.Name & IIf(item.TypeName = vbNullString, vbNullString, " As " & item.TypeName)

            Dim j As Variant
            Dim ref As IdentifierReference
            For Each j In item.References
                Set ref = j
                Debug.Print " >> used in '" & ref.ParentScope.Name & "', line " & ref.StartLine
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function IsMember(ByVal item As DeclarationType) As Boolean
    IsMember = item = DeclarationType_Function _
        Or item = DeclarationType_Procedure _
        Or item = DeclarationType_PropertyGet _
        Or item = DeclarationType_PropertyLet _
        Or item = DeclarationType_PropertySet
End Function
```

Assuming that the above procedure is written in `ThisWorkbook`, it would produce this output (assuming no other code in the project, and no other loaded project):

```
ThisWorkbook.IsMember As Boolean
 >> used in 'IsMember', line 28
 >> used in 'ListMembers', line 14
ThisWorkbook.ListMembers
```

You could use that API to not only iterate members, but also determine who is calling who, and where. And `UserDeclarations` isn't all; Rubberduck also loads all referenced type libraries, so if you iterate `AllDeclarations` you could iterate members of the Excel object model, or of the VBA standard library, and iterate their `References`, too.

Note that the API is still very alpha, and thus still subject to change.

---

> **Disclaimer** I'm directly involved with the Rubberduck project.